# run multiple django project in different virtualenv on apache

Tags: django, apache, virtualhost

I want to run two different django_projects each in different virtualenv.
This is the code :

```
ServerName ubuntu_server_apache

<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName dev.hexxie.com

ErrorLog "/home/ashish/deployments/mysite_dev/conf/mysite_dev_error.log"

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ashish/deployments/mysite_dev/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

Alias /static /home/ashish/deployments/mysite_dev/static_root
<Directory /home/ashish/deployments/mysite_dev/static_root>
Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media /home/ashish/deployments/mysite_prod/data/media
<Directory /home/ashish/deployments/mysite_prod/data/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ashish/deployments/mysite_dev/mysite/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
WSGIPythonPath /home/ashish/deployments/mysite_dev/mysite:/home/ashish/.virtualenvs/mysite_dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages



<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName hexxie.com
ServerAlias *.hexxie.com

ErrorLog "/home/ashish/deployments/mysite_prod/conf/mysite_error.log"

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ashish/deployments/mysite_prod/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

Alias /static /home/ashish/deployments/mysite_prod/static_root
<Directory /home/ashish/deployments/mysite_prod/static_root>
Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media /home/ashish/deployments/mysite_prod/data/media
<Directory /home/ashish/deployments/mysite_prod/data/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ashish/deployments/mysite_prod/mysite/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
WSGIPythonPath /home/ashish/deployments/mysite_prod/mysite:/home/ashish/.virtualenvs/mysite_prod/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

But I am getting internal server error using this apache conf. I feel that  this is due to WSGIPythonPath used twice in conf. `WSGIPythonPath` can't be included inside virtualhost. So how to run two diff django project each on diff virtualenv on apache ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a start, use a daemon process group so each runs in a separate process and then use the `python-home` option on the respective `WSGIDaemonProcess` group directives. See:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/using-python-virtual-environments-with.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how I do it. You'll have to change paths / project names based on your setup, naturally (example is SSL on port 443, but works on port 80 as well):

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

NameVirtualHost *:443
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerName your.server.com
  ErrorLog /home/user/apache_errors.log

  WSGIDaemonProcess project1-https python-home=/home/user/.virtualenvs/project1
  WSGIScriptAlias /project1 /var/www/html/project1/project1/wsgi.py process-group=project1-https application-group=project1-https
  WSGIProcessGroup project1-https
  Alias /project1/static/ /var/www/html/project1/static/

  WSGIDaemonProcess project2-https python-home=/home/user/.virtualenvs/project2
  WSGIScriptAlias /project2 /var/www/html/project2/project2/wsgi.py process-group=project2-https application-group=project2-https
  WSGIProcessGroup project2-https
  Alias /project2/static/ /var/www/html/project2/static/
</VirtualHost>
```

The virtualenv takes care of the Python executable and path when configured in this manner.

Comment: Your ``WSGIProcessGroup`` directives are not needed as you use ``process-group`` option to ``WSGIDaemonProcess``. The latter ``WSGIProcessGroup`` would actually have overridden the first anyway and wouldn't have done what you expect. You also should set ``application-group`` option to ``%{GLOBAL}`` if that is only application in that process group. This avoids issues with some third party C extension modules for Python. Also be aware that if you have 80/443, you don't need to use a separate process group for 443. Can reference the one in the earlier port 80 ``VirtualHost``.

Comment: Wow, straight from the horse's mouth! Thanks for being so involved on SO, it is really informative to have the source authority on mod_wsgi around. Much appreciated!